# How to replace characters other than specified without using Regex in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to replace characters other than specified without using Regular Expression in oracle sql?

For Example:

```
select replace ('rhythm','^h') from dual;

Expected result:

hh
```

Comment: What is wrong with a regular expressions?

Comment: Actually, the question should be 'How to remove characters ...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a non-problem since regular expressions exist, but you could do something like:

```
select listagg(c) within group (order by lvl) from
(
  select level as lvl,
    case when substr('rhythm', level, 1) in ('h', 'H')
      then substr('rhythm', level, 1) end as c
  from dual
  connect by level <= length('rhythm')
);
```

Any characters except `h` and `H` are reported as null by the subquery, and the `listagg()` ignores those nulls. You don't need to specify the characters to exclude, as you would with `translate()`.

I know your example only had lower-case `h` but having an `in()` with a single entry would look odd, so I've included upper-case `H` to match what @Mottor did. It's extensible, anyway, so you can put any characters you're interested in into that list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TRANSLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm)

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('rhythm', 'hHABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefgijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'hH') 
  FROM DUAL;
```

And this here is for @Aleksej  ;)

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 'rhythm bythm dubidah' s, 'ht' c FROM DUAL),
     t2 AS (SELECT TRANSLATE (s, '@' || c, '@') st FROM t1),
     t3 AS (SELECT LISTAGG (str, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) AS sm
           FROM (    SELECT UNIQUE SUBSTR (st, LEVEL, 1) str
                       FROM t2
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (st)))
SELECT TRANSLATE (s, c || sm, c) r
  FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, without need to write the characters to delete:

```
with test(string, character) as
(
 select 'rhythm','h' from dual
)
select rpad(character, length(string) - length(replace(string, character, '')),character)
from test
```

Comment: Cool :) , but does not work for more than one character.